# Lead forum traffic to a website

Tags: seo, redirects, traffic, forum, user-experience

I'm running a small and old forum which got rankings here and there, but I created new pages on the website to provide a better helping source. The goal is to have even better rankings with these new pages.

I guess this will take very long - in the meanwhile, it should be a good idea (helping users) to lead the traffic from a forum thread to the new helping source/page. **But how?**

- Should I just create a new post everywhere, even if the last one is from 2005?

  > This feels somehow wrong due to the time difference
- Would it be okay to edit the first post of a user with a link? It doesn't feel right to me.

  > This feels wrong, because I would use a users property

Is there a better solution for this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes it is.

As an administrator on forum, you have acces to put sticky posts and to put announcment.

Put global announcment and that's it. It will be seen on entire forum and it's subforums.

Comment: Ok, that's a thing. Mhh but that only works roughly, what if I want to lead them specifically per thread? :-) This will make more sense (most of the time).

Comment: That's not necessary. Just put up a global announcment and that's it.

Comment: It is necessary! :D

Answer (score 1):

In order to get more traffic for your new forum page yeah you should create new and interesting thread according to the category you added there. Also, you need to make new users and a few replies. So that the people see that in the thread lots of people involved. And in this way, they will inspire to contribute.